# Integrating C libraries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to integrate C libraries in MATLAB/Simulink.I found that we can only integrate shared library files. Please do let me know if we can integrate the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For integrating C libraries in MATLAB you have the following options:

1. Using mex files (used for integrating function with single entry point).
   Refer to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html
2. Use DLL (in windows), and shared object in Linux.
   Refer to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html

When you need to use C for performance reasons (expand Matlab functionality), consider using mex files.

When you need to use an existing library with many functions, use DLL or SO.

There are many rules you have to follow when interfacing C implementation within MATLAB:

- Matlab matrices memory layout is column major, and C is row major.
- Using C function with pointers requires special attention (there are no pointers in Matlab).
- There are no `enum`s in MATLAB- you need to pass a strings, or replace C `enum` with `int`.
- There are no `union` support in MATLAB.
- There are many other limitations, I can't think of.

You can't just access C libraries from MATLAB.
It's not like accessing Java libraries from MATLAB (if that what you have meant): http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html